# Backward install of cam lock

Tags: self-assembly-furniture

I tried to install a cam lock, but did it backwards. I put the C part into the hole in the furniture and then stuck the screw in. Now it seems hopelessly stuck. I had never done this before (trying to do this w/o bothering my husband). How can I get the screw out? [image]

Comment: May come out with jiggling. Want to turn screw left and right but not pressing down on it, so just rest the driver in it. At same time try to pull and jiggle the insert. You may have to repeat with the screw arrow at different positions till you find the position that the insert pine will come out

Comment: It looks like your problem is that you installed the pin (sticking out the right side of the board) into the cam lock instead of screwing it into the other piece of wood first, correct? In that case, just follow [Jasen's instructions](https://diy.stackexchange.com/a/257348/34147) to unscrew the cam, use a pair of pliers to wiggle the post out, screw the post in, then reinstall.

Answer (score 1):

[image]

Turn the cam part anticlockwise (opposite direction to the arrow) until the triangle points towards the stem part

If it is jammed you may need to use some extra tool on your screwdriver to get extra leverage.

Comment: Once the cam is lined up correctly (it may take a bit of fiddling, since the post isn't held solidly), a pair of pliers to wiggle the post out of the hole may be necessary. I've got some that have plastic on the post and they're a _tight_ fit in the hole.